# Does anyone know what font is used in the Eclipse menu bar?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have a Java swing application running in Windows, Linux and Mac op. systems. Not long ago, the Linux users were growing, and our Swing app always used default system fonts.

[image: Eclipse menu bar]

Now we're working to keep this app with same appearance in those OS. So, I'm trying to discover what font is this used in Eclipse's menu bar. This font has a good resolution, it's so smooth, and it's rendered in the same way on those OS.

Does anyone know what font this is and the size of it?

**Example**

Here is an example using Segoe UI font with 12px:

[image]

The first one is clearly soft than second one rendered in my app. To prepare Font object, I'm using this:

```
Font font=new Font("Segoe UI", Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 12);
UIManager.put("Menu.font", font);
UIManager.put("MenuItem.font", font);
```

I got a better resulting adding this Java options to client GUI:

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dswing.aatext=true
```

Here is result:

[image]

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use Swing, so I have removed the Swing tag.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Eclipse uses a system font, so it could vary depending on the OS, desktop manager, and your own preferences.

Comment: Eclipse menus are rendered by the OS so you get whatever the OS is using.

Comment: So what you are asking is how to reproduce the good font rendering in a Swing app?

Comment: Have you tried `-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on`? (that is 'on' rather than 'lcd')

Comment: Yes, i have. The third image has the render each of them. The strange is, on linux, the font appears that doesn't have any anti-aliasing..even using system defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is this one:

https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=331

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I had seen this Segoe, but Gnome doesn't render it the same way.

Comment: Based on your answer, I tried this: new Font("Segoe UI",Font.PLAIN, 12);...now I'll try it on my linux here.

Answer (score 2):

From this [FAQ](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howbuilddll), it's quite clear that SWT widgets and related properties are OS-dependent:

> SWT uses JNI to interact with the native widgets in the operating system.

SWT jars are platform dependent and they use JNI to load native libraries.